# add input string to url in python

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

I have a project of web scraping . I want to get the name of something for searching as input and add it to the end of my url . i tried the code bellow but it didn't work, the input did not become a part of url

```
search = input()
url= 'https://www.digikala.com/search/?q='+search
```

Comment: Doesn't this work for you?

Comment: This should work, the only exceptions would most likely be the need of conversion of special characters to their Unicode, such as `'` -> `%27`

Comment: Can you please share the output i.e., print the URL string. If you are using Py 2.7 then you might need raw_input, else the code should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `f-strings` were not introduced before python 3.7 so use `.format` instead then:

```
search = input()
url= 'https://www.digikala.com/search/?q={}'.format(search)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, try it:

```
search = input()
url= f'https://www.digikala.com/search/?q={search}'
```

This is called `f-string` formatting.